# Failed to apply plugin class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin'

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-proguard

### Heading #### error

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------

| cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: 11.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_clappus0bapk6o2wizowsqrug.run(E:\fhc-app-temp\platforms\android\build.gradle:148)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.659 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\fhc-app-temp\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services\fhc-build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\fhc-app-temp\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services\fhc-build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).


----------
```

### Heading

### plugin list

E:\fhc-app-temp>cordova plugin list
 - com.moust.cordova.videoplayer 1.0.1 "Video Player"
 - cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 1.2.0 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
 - cordova-plugin-apprate 1.3.0 "AppRate"
 - cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.6 "Badge"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0   "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0    "Console"
cordova-plugin-device  1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email 1.2.6 "EmailComposer"
   cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.12 "EmailComposer"
   cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin" cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
   cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
   cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.25 "Google Firebase Plugin"
   cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.9 "Globalization"
   cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
   cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
   cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
   cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
   cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
   cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar" cordova-plugin-whitelist
      1.3.3 "Whitelist" cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.2.1 "SocialSharing" cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
   cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player 1.0.6 "CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer"
   cordova-sqlite-storage 2.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
   cordova-support-google-services 1.0.0
   "cordova-support-google-services" cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.9.1
   "Diagnostic" es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise" ionic-plugin-keyboard
      2.2.1 "Keyboard"

### build.gradle

```
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
*/

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }

}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/fhc-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-badge/fhc-badge.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-firebase/fhc-build.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-local-notification/fhc-localnotification.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-support-google-services/fhc-build.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*

    ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

    else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
    */

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.gms:google-services:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+        "
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### ionic info

```
cli packages: (E:\fhc-app-temp\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.2.1
npm               : 5.3.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\FHC-02\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

> I am stuck with this error. I had tried each and every way to solve this error but still not able to solve this. plzz help me. If someone have solution for this. thanks in advance.

---

### project.properties

> ## This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
>
> ## Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
>
> #
>
> ## This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
>
> #
>
> ## To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
>
> ## "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
>
> ## project structure.
>
> #
>
> ## To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
>
> ## proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
>
> ## Project target. target=android-26 cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/fhc-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle
>
> cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-badge/fhc-badge.gradle
>   cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
>   cordova.system.library.2=com.google.gms:google-services:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8.0
>   cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-firebase/fhc-build.gradle
>   cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-local-notification/fhc-localnotification.gradle
>   cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.11=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0
>   cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
>   cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-support-google-services/fhc-build.gradle
>   cordova.system.library.13=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
>   cordova.system.library.14=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
>   cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
>   android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib

Comment: update cordova-angular platform and try

Comment: not worked sir. i had tried this trick before also 3 time but still error. And according to your suggestion i have tried it once again but still same error.

Comment: apply my solution, if the problem still persist then you may have to upgrade your gradle version https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me, change the plugin.xml of that particular plugin and change

```
 <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+" />
 <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+" />
```

update it to

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0" />
```

Then delete the android platform, add it again and build the app.

Answer (score 0):

remove below line from the end of `gradle` file and make some other changes that is replace `+` with `11.8.0` for `google and firebase` versions

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and place it below dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.google.gms:google-services:11.8.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+        "
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Update:**
Replace your `project.properties` by the following code, i just removed the duplications and version mismatch

```
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-badge/fhc-badge.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.gms:google-services:11.8.0 
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8.0 
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-firebase/fhc-build.gradle 
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-local-notification/fhc-localnotification.gradle   
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0 cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0 cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0 
    cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0 
    cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0 
    cordova.system.library.11=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0 
    cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-support-google-services/fhc-build.gradle 
    cordova.system.library.14=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+ 
    cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+ 
    android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
```

Comment: I have removed apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' this line from build.gradle and run build command but still same error.

Comment: did you replaced the + sign with exact version. better place for these change would project.properties, as gradle file is generated with every build

Comment: please share your project.properties

Comment: I have posted my project.properties after making changes according to u r suggestion but still same error. plzzzz help me. please look at above in my post

Comment: I have also upgrade my gradle version from 3.3 to 4.1 but still same error

Comment: PLZ someone help me this issue.

Comment: see my answer for update and give it another try. (please indent it by yourself)

Answer (score 0):

..\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-firebase
change The code cordova_plugin_firebase-build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
       transitive = true
    }
}

cdvPluginPostBuildExtras.add({
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
})
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```

..\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services
and change The code is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
ext.postBuildExtras = {
   // apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

and change

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/cordova_plugin_firebase-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1      
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-support-google-services/cordova_plugin_firebase-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=phonegap-plugin-multidex/cordova_plugin_firebase-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.10=com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1
cordova.system.library.11=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true